# In p5.js web editor, the keyPressed() function is just flat out not working

Tags: p5.js

I personally don't know how much help I can get in this situation. I was trying to make a Flappy bird sketch off of Daniel Shiffman's videos using the p5.js web editor, however when the keyPressed() function was used (which I am familiar with because I did a bunch with Processing), I would get no response. Now originally, it was if(key === ' ') { that was being used, and when the space bar was pressed, the sketch would reset. However, when I tried with other letters, then eventually to just the keyPressed example from the reference, it still wouldn't do anything. It even worked on the website's example, however it wouldn't work in the web editor. What is happening?
Example code:

```
let value = 0;
function draw() {
  fill(value);
  rect(25, 25, 50, 50);
}
function keyPressed() {
  if (value === 0) {
    value = 255;
  } else {
    value = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Have you tried clicking inside the canvas first to make sure it has keyboard focus?

Comment: yeah that works

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//in the draw function
if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW /*or what ever*/)) {
//action
}
```